# Dereference list::end()

Tags: c++11, gcc, stdlist

I was playing around with `std::list`. Similarly to other containers, `std::list::end` refers to the past-the-end element of a std::list ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/end/)).

So, we would expect the below code to print `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (which it does):

```
std::list<int> l { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << ", ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

However, the second line of the second code snippet should **not** print `5`, but it does:

```
std::cout << *l.begin() << std::endl;
std::cout << *l.end() << std::endl;
```

Output: `1` and `5`.

Why? I'm using GCC 11 and C++11 (same for C++20 btw).

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined, which can include "produces garbage data" or "miraculously produces data you wanted" or "demons fly out of your nose". There is no "answer" to this.

Comment: If it should *not* print `5`, what do you think it should print instead?

Comment: @Barmar yeah I got it, it's undefined. Couldn't find that on the link though. To be honest, I expected a crash, or a max int, or smth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the reason if you build in debug mode, with the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` command line flag:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/debug/safe_iterator.h:270:
Error: attempt to dereference a past-the-end iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator "this" @ 0x0x7fff50ac8670 {
      type = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::__cxx1998::_List_iterator<int>, std::__debug::list<int, std::allocator<int> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = past-the-end;
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::list<int, std::allocator<int> >' @ 0x0x7fff50ac85d0
    }
Aborted
```

As with other containers, dereferencing the `end()` iterator is undefined. It only happens to work by accident in non-debug mode.